# Installing a Distribution Certificate signed iOS app through Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile

Is it possible to install and run a build on iPhone through Xcode by manually signing it with a distribution certificate? I tried doing the same, but it says:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Is this some error that can be taken care of, like is there something problematic with the provisioning profile itself or it isn't possible at all?

Also, just in case it is possible, would that allow me to test the app as if I am doing it in production, like using IAP etc in real production environment?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Application with Distribution certificate than there are 2 options available

**1. With Xcode :**

- There are 2 different types of Provisioning Profiles available in Distribution (AdHoc & AppStore)
- If you are going to install directly with Xcode than you can make AdHoc Distribution Profile & add your Device Id in It & install it via Xcode
- Make sure you won't be able to debug with this Provisioning

**2. With TestFlight :**

- Second option is you can use Apples TestFlight beta program to install App through App Store Distribution App
- For that you need to upload application on App Store same as we are uploading live apps.
- Than go to the Beta testing section & Invite the beta testers

Hope this helps to everyone.

Comment: In #2, we are already using TestFlight but it doesn't let us test In App subscriptions with real payments. Also, we cannot release the app on the App Store as it is a sample app that mimicks the In App Purchase workflow for various apps across the company. It's a global company and we do not have access to the actual apps, our team just provides for the integration of payment workflows.